# UICollectionView crashes when rearranging items between sections

Tags: ios, crash, uicollectionview

I have trouble animating changes between sections in a `UICollectionView`, my program keeps crashing, what is wrong with it?

I have a collection view which has four sections:

> 0: A
>   1: B
>   2: C
>   3: D

I want to transform it to have only three sections with the same items:

> 0: A
>   1: B, C
>   2: D

And I want to animate this transformation:

```
// Initial state

NSArray *source = @[ @[@"A"], @[@"B"], @[@"C"], @[@"D"] ];


// Some data source methods

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [source[section] count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return [source count];
}


// Transformation: that works but I have to keep an empty section

source = @[ @[@"A"], @[@"B", @"C"], @[@"D"], @[] ];

[collection performBatchUpdates:^{
    [collection moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]
                        toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]];
    [collection moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:1]
                        toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:1]];
    [collection moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:2]
                        toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:1]];
    [collection moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:3]
                        toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:2]];
} completion:nil];


// Transformation: that crashes!

source = @[ @[@"A"], @[@"B", @"C"], @[@"D"] ];

[collection performBatchUpdates:^{
    [collection moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]
                        toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0]];
    [collection moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:1]
                        toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:1]];
    [collection moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:2]
                        toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:1]];
    [collection moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:3]
                        toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:2]];
    [collection deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:3]];
} completion:nil];
```

I keep getting crashes, either an internal assertion failure: `Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimations]...`, or sometimes, even more weird, a malloc error: `incorrect checksum for freed object...`.

If I don't call `deleteSections:` it doesn't work either. If I put first, it doesn't change anything. If I remove the `moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` which have the same source and destination, it doesn't change anything. If I don't do it in a batch block, it obviously crashes at the first command.
Did I overlook something?

Comment: have you ever found a solution for that? It seems like using moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath: and deleteSections: in the same batch update always leads to crashes but would like a confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

An extract from this very interesting [article](http://www.raizlabs.com/2013/10/animating_items_uicollectionview/) about UICollectionView:

> When inserting a new section within the batch update block, one must
>   not insert any items into that section – that will be handled
>   implicitly. In fact, inserting items into a newly-inserted section in
>   a batch update block creates “ghost” layers which get stuck in the
>   collection view layer hierarchy. Presumably this is a just bug with
>   UICollectionView, as this behavior is not documented and no exception
>   is thrown

Knowing this, I find it not surprising at all that deleting of section and `moveItemFromIndexPath:toIndexPath` do not work well together either. I guess it's "kind of the same bug".

**The solution I used:**

I put a fake invisible cell in the section I should have deleted. That permitted me to keep the same behavior as if I had done a `moveItemFromIndexPath:toIndexPath:`. Of course, I adapted my datasource accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
source = @[ @[@"A"], @[@"B", @"C"], @[@"D"] ];

[collection performBatchUpdates:^{
    [collection moveItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:2]
                        toIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:1]];
    [collection deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:2]];
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: Actually I think the problem is we can't mix section and item updates that can conflict. If we delete section 2, it means we also delete the items contained in section 2, but we already asked to move an item in section 2, so I guess we can't at the same time move and delete the item... I feel like the only solution is to keep the number of sections constant.